# How to `str.join` two list to strings of all combinations in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to get a list of `('A_1','A_2','B_1','B_2','C_1','C_2')`, with something like `'_'.join()` and `[(x, y) for x in ['A','B','C'] for y in [1,2]]`.

How to write this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does this edit makes the question not a duplicate ?

Comment: Nope; you're asking two questions (how to get pairs, how to format pairs) both of which are already covered on SO and elsewhere. You need to decompose your problems and do research around the parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

On `python3.6+`

```
import itertools
letters = ['A','B','C']
nums = [1, 2]
result = [f"{l}_{n}" for l, n in itertools.product(letters, nums)]
```

Or in lower python versions:

```
result = ["{}_{}".format(l, n) for l, n in itertools.product(letters, nums)]
```

Output:

```
>>> result
['A_1', 'A_2', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2']
```

Comment: `.format` reads more clear.

Comment: @Galaxy, that is a matter of opinion. Format strings are pretty good and straight forward to understand in **my** opinion.

Comment: Be aware that f-strings are only available from Python 3.6 onwards.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: @YohanGrember, yeah, that is why I added both, let me make it explictly. Thanks!